# Meteor validate object and clean object with simple schema

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

I have defined a schema for a meteor mongo collection using smpl-schema to validate and clean object.

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
const schema = new SimpleSchema({
  name:String,
  age:Number,
  address:{
   type:String,
   optional:True
  }
}, {
  clean: true,
});
```

data :

```
let doc = {
  name:' ',
  age:10,
}
```

Here my function to validate :

```
function validateData(doc){
let validationContext = schema.newContext();
validationContext.validate(doc);
if (!validationContext.isValid()) throw JSON.stringify(validationContext.validationErrors())

return true
}
```

It's error, it's output : `Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object [ValidateDataError]`

Comment: Can you please add the code that you use to validate the object and it's error output.

Comment: it's not error ,but it's not clean object before insert to Mongodb. I want to clean object before insert to Mongodb

Comment: But what do you expected to be cleaned from the above given document?

Comment: I was edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your schema, `optional` should be set to `true`

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
const schema = new SimpleSchema({
   name:String,
   age:Number,
   address:{
   type:String,
   optional:true
   }
}, {
   clean: true,
});
```